# How to transfer installed apps from one account to another

Tags: applications, google-account

On my Note 2 I have two accounts configured

my.email@gmail.com
my.work.email@company.com

Usually I have the Play Store configured to buy/install apps under my.email@gmail.com but somehow it got changed to my work email a while back. Before I noticed this, I installed ~20 apps using the my.work.email@company.com

Is there a way for me to re-associate those purchases with my.email@gmail.com without manually reinstalling each app? And how will this be different for free vs paid apps that I installed while using my.work.email@company.com?

Comment: I have 101 rep here, but apparently that is not greater than the 10 I need to answer here, so I created this question: Transfer Google Play app to another account https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/223912/transfer-google-play-app-to-another-account

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's currently no way to do this. Free apps can be re-downloaded under the appropriate account, of course, but Google has no provision for moving paid apps (or free ones, in bulk) from one account to another. The [Google Play support page](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=2520903&page=ts.cs) has their official stance on this:

> At this time, it's not possible to transfer apps from one account to
>   another.
>
> Some developers are willing to issue refunds for purchases on old
>   accounts if you repurchase the app(s) using a new account. You can
>   always reach out to the developer of an app, and you can find their
>   contact information by following these steps:
>
> 1. Visit Google Play and
>      select the app in question
> 2. On the app's description page, scroll down
>      to the Developer section
> 3. Find either an email address, phone number or
>      website listed.

Comment: Accurate answer.  Google could easily develop a way to do this, but I think they prefer you just spend your money to buy all the apps again.  So much for "do no evil"... again.

Answer (score 2):

While you can't transfer apps, you can sync the appropriate email (with all the apps purchased) to multiple devices so you have access to the apps.  Just be sure to DESELECT all the other things (gmail, calendar, etc.) so the only thing that is synched from that account is the apps (Google Play Store).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information I've collected on how to move forward with this problem. As instructed, I've added quoted information from the pertinent pages in case the links expire:

What about if an account has been hacked or is the ongoing target of a phishing attack? Is there no way to transfer apps under these circumstances? Where do I complain to Google about this?

From a Google Support Search (https://support.google.com/mail/search?q=transfer+app+account):

How do I transfer all data between two Gmail accounts? https://support.google.com/mail/thread/10761789?hl=en

Transfer my apps and Play store balance to a different Gmail account. https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/37917054

> This Forum is for assistance with Gmail issues.  Answers to Google
>   Play questions including the impact on purchased apps will be found
>   here: Google Play Community

The first link has the most upvotes, but is locked. The second refers the question to Google Play Support, so search (https://support.google.com/googleplay/search?q=transfer+app+account):

Transfer Playstore app purchases to my new account https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/16840581?hl=en

Is it possible to shift a purchased app to my account? https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/15924856?hl=en

How to transfer purchases from one google account to another https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/9838585?hl=en

> How can I transfer these purchases? I don't want them existing in both
>   places. I will NEVER go back and want them there (this is a very old
>   yahoo-email based google account -- before marrying, I created a gmail
>   account that would have my maiden name, if you are worried about
>   divorce). I want to be able to open up my google play, and see
>   anything and everything I can download. I don't want to repurchase the
>   items, because I already bought them and I own them already.

The first two are locked, and the last question has 165 upvotes and is a very legitimate situation. You can Subscribe to get updates on any official development, and upvote as well.