# Moving app sync from one google account to another

Tags: google-play-store, sync

Okay I am using a new Gmail account on my PlayStore to browse my tablet. Now the problem is that all the apps that I downloaded using my first account, so when I log into the using my second account I don't see the apps of my first account.

I have the question on whether we can move paid apps between accounts over [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42562/how-to-transfer-installed-apps-from-one-account-to-another).

But all my apps are free, can I move them from one account to another ?

The list of the apps are as follows-:

1. ES File Explorer
2. Facebook
3. Firefox
4. Youtube
5. aTorrent
6. Gmail
7. Google
8. Google News and Weather
9. Google Talkback
10. Google Text to speech
11. Hangouts

Comment: Are you still using/needing the old account on your device? While paid apps cannot be transferred, this is possible for free apps in a way.

Comment: @Izzy Yes if I use the old account then my Playstore displays all apps correctly. can you please tell me the procedure on how to transfer them

Comment: The procedure I have in mind requires you to remove your old account. Is that acceptable for you?

Comment: @Izzy Yes Absolutely

Answer (score 0):

Several of the apps you list most likely came pre-installed with your device (e.g. Gmail, Google, Google Talkback). Keeping that in mind brings up the question: How did they end up being associated with your account? Which leads to a possibility to achieve what you want:

1. Delete the "old" Google account from that device
2. Wait a little. It usually doesn't take longer than a day that a process of the Google Play app scans your device for installed apps, and links them to your (new) account if they have no link yet (that's how the pre-installed apps ended up here)
3. Once that had happened, and if you still need the "old" account for some purpose, it *should* be safe to re-create it (I'm not 100% sure about this step, as I've never tried it).

Comment: I had to install all Google Apps since I am using a custom ROM(Cyanogen). Have you ever tried this ? Waiting for a day then having the apps associated to another account ?

Comment: Not actively. But the other way around: I wanted to get rid of update notifications, so I detached apps from Playstore using TitaniumBackup. Worked for about a day, then they've been back. See: [How to get rid of update notifications for a given app in Google Play Store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/58021/16575)

Comment: No I don't it will work in my case. You see you downloaded the apps using the same account you were using. But my apps are downloaded using another google account all together.

Comment: I'll have to correct you, Heidi: Most of the apps I'm talking about here were not downloaded with that account – but either came pre-installed, or were "side-loaded". So it wasn't even any Google account at all where those came from. // Why not trying it out? If it really won't work (which I doubt), you could still re-add your "old account".